# How can this be worded better?

Tags: idioms, prepositions

How can this be better expressed?

> In respect of Anna's written wishes, there will be no funeral.

Comment: With respect for..., Respecting..., Out of respect for..., and the answers below.

Comment: Hi user69013. What do you mean by *"better* expressed?" What do you think is wrong with it currently?

Comment: @nxx: I think fairly obviously the "problem" with OP's version is that usually when a statement starts with *"In respect of X"*, it means *what follows is a statement **about** X*, not *what follows is a statement reflecting recognition and **respect for** X*.

Comment: Sure, but that is not necessarily what the OP thinks is "wrong". The question lacks details and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There are several good ways to express the thought. Here are a few:

> We will respect Anna's written wishes and forgo a funeral.
>
> We will respect Anna's written wish to forgo a funeral.
>
> As Anna requested in writing, there will be no funeral.
>
> At Anna's written request there will be no funeral.
>
> To respect Anna's wishes, no funeral will be held.
>
> There will be no funeral per Anna's written request.